# How to use onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState methods with fragments?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, onrestoreinstancestate

I have two `Fragments`. One of it has one `EditText` and one `Button`. The other one has only one `ListView`. How to save datas which are in `ListView` in case of any change in the orientation of emulator?

My problem is that I don't know how to save and restore my `ListView` when I rotate the emulator's screen. Where should I put the `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` methods and how to use them?

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AddToDoFragment.OnToDoAddedListener {

private ArrayList<String> todoItems;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    ToDoListFragment listToDo = new ToDoListFragment();
    listToDo = (ToDoListFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.list_view_fragment);
    todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);
    listToDo.setListAdapter(adapter);
}

public void OnToDoAdded(String newToDo) {
    todoItems.add(newToDo);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

AddToDoFragment.java

```
public class AddToDoFragment extends Fragment {

public interface OnToDoAddedListener {

    public void OnToDoAdded (String newToDo);

}

private OnToDoAddedListener onToDoAddedListener;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_to_do_fragment, container, false);

    final EditText edittext = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String text = edittext.getText().toString();
            onToDoAddedListener.OnToDoAdded(text);
            edittext.setText("");
        }
    });

    return view;

}

 @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
      super.onAttach(activity);
      if (activity instanceof OnToDoAddedListener) {
        onToDoAddedListener = (OnToDoAddedListener) activity;
      } else {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
            + " must implemenet AddToDoFragment.OnToDoAddedListener");
      }
    }
   }
```

ToDoListFragment.java

```
public class ToDoListFragment extends ListFragment {
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to override the `onSaveInstanceState` method of your activity so that you know when the state needs to be saved. Then you will also need to update your `onCreate` method to check if the `savedInstanceState` is `null`. If it is `null` then the activity hasn't been initiated. This is the example for your `MainActivity` class, and you can go from there:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AddToDoFragment.OnToDoAddedListener {

private ArrayList<String> todoItems;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    } else {
        todoItems = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("todoItemTag");//the tag must match what the variable was saved with
    }

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    ToDoListFragment listToDo = new ToDoListFragment();
    listToDo = (ToDoListFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.list_view_fragment);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);
    listToDo.setListAdapter(adapter);
}

public void OnToDoAdded(String newToDo) {
    todoItems.add(newToDo);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

//Saving the instance by overriding this function
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putStringArrayList("todoItemTag", todoItems);//it would be advised to make the tags a static final String
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

PS: I don't think the `onRestoreInstanceState` method is really necessary. I guess I have never used it before. I believe that you should be able to provide the same functionality with the `null` check in the `onCreate` method.

Comment: Thank you for your interest but Unfortunately I take an error The method putParcelableArrayList(String, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList<String>)

Comment: and also getParcelableArrayList method gives an error like this    Bound mismatch: The generic method getParcelableArrayList(String) of type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String). The inferred type String is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Parcelable>

Comment: See my new edit. You will want to use get/set `StringArrayList` instead of the `ParcelableArrayList`

Comment: i applied what you suggest but still it does not work. when i rotate the emulator screen previous listview datas are lost. any more suggestion?

Comment: ooovvv ok ı saw what i'm missing i recreate my arraylist so it show empty list each trial. when i delete that line it works perfectly.
Thank you very much again...

Comment: I was wondering if that was it. You are welcome and good luck in the future!